# Crash In User Login Flow

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, wso2, wso2-iot

I booted up the wso2 server and attempted to login with a new user, and I'm getting this crash:

> [2015-07-24 14:33:50,128] ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext} -  JSPException while including path '/user-registration/add_user.jsp'. 
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
>       at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
>       at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603)
>       at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:335)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>       at ...

It seemed like there's a similar error in the jira pipeline:

https://www.wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-4616

EDIT:
I'm running WSO2 1.1.0 from the download link here:
(https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Downloading+the+Product)

I'm running it on Yosemite (10.10.3)

My JDK version is 1.8.0_45-b14

Comment: what is the product and the version?

Comment: Can u share the environment info and product info e,g. OS, product, version, jdk version

Comment: Updated to share OS, Product, version and jdk version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs if the following parameter is missing in `[$HOME]/bin/wso2server.sh` file.

Add this value at where the other `-D` parameters are defined in `wso2server.sh` file.

```
-D org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false \
```